# How to call a python method from robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I need to call a python method from robot framework.

```
def getRandomEmails():
    a = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(16))
    email = a + '@' + 'gmail.com'
    return email
```

This function is written in EnvVar.py file
How can I use the returned value from this method in Robot Framework. I have tried almost many ways, but nothing works. 
please help.

Comment: is `EnvVar.py` intended to be a library of keywords? Or, are you just trying to pick one function out of a module to run?

Comment: There are many methods in that python file.I just want to call a method from EnvVar.py

Answer (score 8):

### Using Evaluate

Exactly how to do it on your system depends on how your files are organized and how you've configured robot, but in short, [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) from the BuiltIn library is the keyword that lets you run arbitrary methods from importable modules.

Example:

For this example I've created a file named EnvVar.py in the current working directory. It has the following contents:

```
import random, string

def getRandomEmails():
    a = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(16))
    email = a + '@' + 'gmail.com'
    return email
```

I then created a file named "example.robot" that looks like this:

```
*** Test cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  evaluate  EnvVar.getRandomEmails()  modules=EnvVar
    log  result: ${result}
```

Since the current working directory isn't by default on my PYTHONPATH (your setup may be different), I have to tell robot to include the current directory on PYTHONPATH. I can do that with the `--pythonpath` option.

```
$ robot --pythonpath . example.robot
```

### Creating a keyword library

Another solution is to create your own keyword library that exposes this function as a keyword.

For example, assuming you can import EnvVar, you could write a library named "Util" (Util.py) that creates a keyword that calls this function:

```
# Util.py
import EnvVar

def get_random_emails():
    return EnvVar.getRandomEmails()
```

You would then use this in a test like any other keyword library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Util.py

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  Get Random Emails
    log  result: ${result}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's the only method you want to add than you could add `keyword` decorator i.e:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword

@keyword
def getRandomEmails():
    a = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for i in range(16))
    email = a + '@' + 'gmail.com'
    return email
```

And obviously you should import in settings as library

Comment: Actually there are many methods in the EnvVar.py file. I just need to use one of the method which is having no arguments.